# Resource for Download of ActiveTcl 8.5.11

Tags: python, ide, python-3.x, python-idle, activetcl

Hey I am new to python development and just figured out which version of ActiveTcl works with my version of python and my OS. I went on the ActiveTcl website following the link from pyhton.org and I seemed to get only versions 8.5.12 and 8.6.0 for free download. I would like to know if there is any other place on the site or on the web where ActiveTcl is available for free download or whether ActiveTcl 8.5.11 and below is part of a paid software package that we are required to purchase from ActiveTcl.

Please do oblige with a reply, as I would really like to start working with IDLE for python development.

Comment: you dont need to download activetcl to have a fully working python installation. Pythoninstallers have all the libraries you need for tkinter graphics.

Comment: Right but I need it for the IDLE in python3 to work so I would like to know where I might be able to download it.

Comment: I have MAC 10.7.4 and I have python 2.7 which is the version that came with the mac and I installed python3 which comes with IDLE but I guess I need the ActiveTcl for the GUI to work for IDLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.python.org/getit/mac/tcltk/) there is updated info about available ActiveTcl releases for Mac OS X and a link to download the recommended  [ActiveTcl, 8.5.11.1](http://downloads.activestate.com/ActiveTcl/releases/8.5.11.1/)

Comment: I actually downloaded the right version and added it to my path and everything but the error still persists. When I go to preferences in the python shell, it exits unexpectedly would you have any idea why this is happening still?

Comment: I'm not a Mac user. I am not sure what do you mean with 'go to preferences in the python shell'. Do you mean in idle ?. In any case, check the warnings in the link specially those related with different compatibilities of 32bit and 64bit systems and distributions.

Comment: oh ok sorry about that when I go to the IDLE menu and click on the preferences option IDLE "crashes unexpectedly" this is the exact error that was supposed to be avoided by downloading ActiveTcl 8.5.11 but it didn't so I was wondering whether you knew how to fix it. But anyway thanks for all your help I really appreciate it.